# Count array from start of specific index

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a function in PHP where I can start counting from a specific index of an array?

Example:

```
$array = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 'string', 5, 6, 7);

var_dump(count($array)); // 8 items
```

Function similar what I need:

```
$array = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 'string', 5, 6, 7);

var_dump(countFromIndex($array, 2)); // 6 items (started from 3)
```

Comment: The question is unclear. Do you want to count from the item at the second position, of the first occurrence of 2? Very different things

Comment: $pos=5; $count= count($array); $lenFromPos= $count - ($pos + 1);

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by specific index? Are you looking to start counting at the second object, or the object with the key '2'?

Comment: Please specify your problem in implementing the `countFromIndex` function. It's not specifically clear what you're asking for. By default no such function exists in PHP AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to get the number of items starting at index number 2, you can simply use `count($array) - 2` ?

Comment: This wouldn't work, as she's looking for a specific index and might not know where it is.

Comment: @Grim... If it really is about indexes then my solution works fine. If the idea is to find the first **value** that matches '2', then yes, it won't work, but then the question is very unclear, don't you think?

Comment: @Grim... then i see no reason to down votes answers to below zero

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I also misunderstood the question originally (or maybe I didn't, who knows), and now I can't change my vote unless you edit your question (which I will certainly do).

Answer (score 1):

No, you'd need to write one.
The simplest (not best, just what I can pull from the top of my head) method would be something like

```
function countFrom($array, $indexFrom) {
$counter = 0;
$start = false;
foreach ($array as $k=>$v) {
    if ($k == $indexFrom) {
        $start = true;
    }
    if ($start) {
        $counter ++;
    }
}
return $counter;
}
```

Or, perhaps less memory intensive:

```
function countFrom($array, $indexFrom) {
$start = false;
$counter = 0; // experiment to see if this should be 0 or 1
foreach ($array as $k=>$v) {
    if ($k == $indexFrom) {
        $new = array_splice($array, $counter);
        return count($new);
    }
    $counter ++;
}
```

Comment: Again down to the ambiguity of the question, this potentially wont work if they in fact want the count from a value, instead of a key. Easy fix though, changing $k to $v, just reinforcing the questions vagueness.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
function countFromIndex($array, $index)
{
    $values = array_values($array);
    $count = count($values);
    $search = 0;
    for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++)
    {
        $search++;
        if($values[$i] === $index) break;
    }
    return $count-$search;
}

$array = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 'string', 5, 6, 7);
var_dump(countFromIndex($array, 2)); // 6 items (started from 3)
var_dump(countFromIndex($array, 'string')); // 3 items (started from 5)
var_dump(countFromIndex($array, 7)); // 0 items (started from ?)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$total = count($array);
$count = 0;

for($i = 2; $i < $total; $i++)
{
    $count++;
}
```

Change `$i = 2` to set start point.

Comment: Why not `$count = count($array) - 2;` ?